# Visual Studio project file format - does that "new one" have an actual name?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm in the process of converting my "old style" .csproj files to the "new ones" (the .net core format). Works quite fine and I really like that new format.

The thing that bothers me most is - how do I actually call that new format? Does that thing have a name? Or is everyone calling them "new" and "old" formats?

Not really a technical question, but I'd really like to know...

Comment: For googling right now, `new csproj`. SDK or MSBuild project format are more official but I'd bet even the SO and MS Build people call it the `new csproj` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The development team is calling it SDK-style or SDK-format:

> "SDK-style" or "SDK-format" is what we're calling it.

Authoritative Source : David Kean on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/davkean/status/1038035220665065477)

Comment: Authoritative indeed. Thanks for finding out!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [project page](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/master/docs/feature-comparison.md), the old one is called *Legacy Project System*, while the new is called *(New) Project System* or *Common Project System* (which is more precisely the base implementation of the new project system). I've also seen it as *.NET Core Project System.*

Comment: Thanks for that link - very nice information even beyond the name. Accepting Panagiotis' answer though because that's closer to an actual name ;-)